# Php problem with passing name of uploaded file

Tags: php, variables

I asked similar question yestarday but didnt get any response which would help me, what I want to do is to 
1.upload a file to server
2.get the name of the file so if it was 'hope.jpg' file and was uploaded to a folder called 'uploads' I would need sth like 'uploads/hope.jpg' later on.

I tried to pass it as variable its not working showing this information:

There was an error uploading the file, please try again!
Warning: fopen(uploads/) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.php on line 112

Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.php on line 121

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in D:\www\2010-msc\businesscards\QRCodeAPI.class.php on line 130
error in decode:

Here is html form I used:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
 Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
 </form>
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; ?>" method="POST">
         <label for="action"> Method:</label>
         <select id="action" name="action">
                <option value="generate" <?php echo $action == "generate" ?    'selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>generate</option>
        <option value="encode" <?php echo $action == "encode" ? 'selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>encode</option>
        <option value="decode" <?php echo $action == "decode" ? 'selected="selected"' : ""; ?>>decode</option>
    </select>
    </br>
    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <input type="text" id="message" name="message" value="<?php echo $message; ?>" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

then I upload a file like that:

```
// Where the file is going to be placed 
 $target_path = "uploads/";

 /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
$a = basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
    echo "uploads/". $a;
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

And after the file is uploaded I tried to decode that with

```
$json = $api->decode ("uploads/". $a);
    $start='{"content":"';
    $pos_start = strpos($json, $start);

    $end='"}';
    $pos_end = strpos($json, $end);

    if ($pos_start === false || $pos_end === false)

    {
    echo "error in decode";
    exit();
    }

    $wiadomosc = substr($json,12,$pos_end - 12);

    echo $wiadomosc;
    exit();

    break;
```

Unfortunately, line `$json = $api->decode ("uploads/". $a);` brings just some errors, but if you write manually the name of the file on the server like `$json = $api->decode ("uploads/hope.jpg");` everything works as it should. Could you give me any advice on how to get the name of the file as if it was input manually cuz apparently its not working when I put variable instead!! thanks for all responses

Answer (score 0):

Should name be tmp_name? .......